# pipe awk output in sed command

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, sed, awk

I have multiple lines in a file names.txt, let's say

```
my name is Jim your name please
what is good Harry potter
how is he Jhony and me
```

and so on , more than 500 lines.

I use awk command to search/ print only names `awk "{ print $4; }" names.txt` all names are on 4th position on each line

following command outputs

```
Jim
Harry
Jhony
```

and so on, more than 500 names.

I use sed command to print lines before each line which matches pattern. list.txt already have many lines. let's say

```
hero is always good and have alpha name
jungle is also called forest and beta owner
carrots are sweet have gama solution
```

sed command search word `have` and add line before pattern match line

```
sed -i "/have/ s/^/oslo good owner="Jim" and too good\n/" list.txt
```

and its works, but write all line with same name.

I want to use awk command result in sed, e.g require output in list.txt file should be

```
olso good owner="Jim" and too good
hero is always good and have alpha name
jungle is also called forest and beta owner
olso good owner="Harry" and too good
carrots are sweet have gama solution
```

and so on, till list.txt file ends.

working in windows-10 environment command prompt

Comment: Googling `sed add line before phrase` returns for example https://fabianlee.org/2018/10/28/linux-using-sed-to-insert-lines-before-or-after-a-match/ among a lot others. Expressions like "not successful" and "command not working" aren't helpful. Instead consider "When I do X happens Y" with exact commands and results - thats a LOT easier to troubleshoot than "doesn't work". Also more descriptive question titles help understand what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks I edited my question, and tried to follow your instructions as much as I can.

Comment: I'm not convinced that removing the information that something is failing actually helps. What I meant was instead of saying "awk doesn't work" explain exactly how `awk` fails. If your `sed` command contains only the name "Jim" you will get "Jim" every time. You need to figure out how to use a variable. I'd suggest checking [GNU Bash Reference](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html), [TLDP Advanced Bash Scripting](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/), [GNU Sed Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) etc... a lot of resources are easily found.

Comment: I am not expert in understanding these Guides, thats why I just asked rather than going expert in this, I am pure Routing, Switching, Firewall, Network guy. please consider

Comment: I'm just pointing out that there are any number of tutorials easily found with  simple internet searches, for different levels starting from 0 - `sed for beginners` or `awk for beginners`. Even for specific things, like adding a line before a pattern with `sed` - did you check that link? If you're able to understand Cisco manuals, any scripting tutorial is a piece of cake. Speaking from personal experience. You do need to put in some effort. Members of the community will help if you run into a wall, but nobody will write a script for you. Again speaking from personal experience.

Comment: I know how to add line before pattern match line, but problem is how to call awk output in sed, these guides does not have this solution

Comment: As you're describing this, you don't need to. You need a loop that reads value to a variable from the text file you produced with `awk`, then use that variable instead of "Jim" in your `sed` line. Again, easily searchable, for example here's just the first result of many when googling how to read variable from file: https://www.tecmint.com/different-ways-to-read-file-in-bash-script/